# Testing Mongoose model required properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I recently started developing apps with node.js, express, and mongoose. I decided to use mocha as a testing framework and is wondering how would I unit test mongoose.model properties for validity.

So if I had a model defined like this:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true}
});

var userModel = new mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I'm assuming that stating "require: true" means that userSchema.name must be defined and not null.

How do I test that when I instantiate a userModel, I must provide it with an object containing a name property that is not null or undefined?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Mockgoose](https://github.com/mccormicka/Mockgoose) for writing unit tests with mongoose models without the need to have a mongodb instance running.

You could write a simple test like this:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        mockgoose = require('mockgoose');

    mockgoose(mongoose);

    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var SimpleSchema = new Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    });
    mongoose.model('SimpleModel', SimpleSchema);

    it('fails to save document with missing name', function(done) {
        var simpleModel = new SimpleModel({
            name: undefined
        });
        simpleModel.save(function(err) {
            should.exist(err);
            done();
        });
    });
```

Then define different tests with different values for name (null, undefined, etc.) or even an empty object (i.e. an object without name property).